# Proof about Robin's inequality for odd numbers

Tags: number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

In this [article](https://www.emis.de/journals/JTNB/2007-2/article03.pdf) (Theorem 1.2) there is a proof for Robin's inequality for odd numbers,
$\sigma(n)/n< e^{\gamma}\log(\log(n))$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $\sigma(n)$ is the divisor function. The proof is not hard but uses Euler's Totient function and other considerations.

In this other [preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.09307.pdf) (Theorem 3.4), the same theorem is stated but a much simpler proof is presented. I think there must be some kind of mistake in the proof because it is too easy compared to the proof already published but I'm not sure.

The author uses the bound

$\sigma(n)/n<e^{\gamma}\log(\log(n))+\frac{0.6483}{\log(\log(n))}$

and the fact that the divisor function is multiplicative. In the following way:

$\sigma(n)/n=s(n)=s(2n)/s(2)<2/3(e^{\gamma}\log(\log(2n))+\frac{0.6483}{\log(\log(2n))})< e^{\gamma}\log(\log(n))$

Is there any mistake in this proof?

Comment: the method is sound. Note this:  any number that has a chance of violating Robin's  inequality,  and larger than the 5040, is superabundant and has prime factorization  very similar to the nearby Colossally Abundant numbers. This rules out odd numbers in any case,  as the exponent on the prime 2 must be at least as large as the exponent of any other prime factor.  I am more impressed with the result on primorials.

Comment: @WillJagy I was skeptical because It seemed impossible that the authors of the first article did not think about that simple proof as well as all the other theorems that use the same technique.

Comment: Slightly different description of  numbers with (very) large $\sigma(n) / n .$   For a positive integer $w,$   let $n$   be the least common multiple of $1,2,3,4,5,6, ... , w-1,   w.$  This is $e^{\psi(w)}$  where  $\psi(w) $ is Chebyshev's second function. These numbers  are  quite different from odd numbers, and violations of Robin's inequality must come from numbers with similar prime factorizations. Briefly,  the exponent of a prime $p$  should be proportional to $1/\log p,$

Comment: A year and a half has gone by and no one has said it's good or bad.

Comment: "much simpler proof". In fact the author uses a theorem which is not so easy to proof.